# Should I supply a 1x app icons for an iPhone only app targeting iOS7?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios7, retina-display

I'm working on an iPhone only app that targets iOS7.

As far as regular assets go I'm happy supplying @2x and @3x versions, only.

However, I'm not 100% sure how non-retina devices will handle the **app icon**, if @1x versions of the various sizes are not supplied?

For example, the default setup in Xcode for the *AppIcon* in `Images.xcassets` is as follows:

[image]

However, if I check the `iPad: iOS7 and Later Sizes` I get this:

[image]

As part of my testing I've been running the app on an old, iPad Mini (which is non-retina). In the development-test environment *it doesn't* get an app icon when the app is run on the device (it gets the white, icon placeholder image).

Will that be the same for app downloads from the store? (App is downloaded with no app icon). If so, why is it not *required* to add the @1x versions of the app icon?

Comment: In fact, you may be rejected before by the Validations of your archive.

Comment: @Larme - this is part of what I've been wondering (especially after seeing another, related question), and what led to me asking the question... To add a bit more info, I've distributed a number of builds via *TestFlight* / *iTunesConnect* and that process involves validating the archive. (I think) Any of those builds that I've uploaded to iTunesConnect could be selected as the build to submit for review...